# Detect page change for one page apps JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, ember.js

I'm wondering if anyone has a solution for tracking "page" changes for one-page apps?

I understand the concept of a one-page app in that all the html/css for a page is preloaded and the pages are constructed based on dictating which elements of a page to hide/show. Even though technically it's a one-page app, the perception of the user is that it is several pages/experiences.

What's the best way to differentiate/track these pages/experiences in a one-page app environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router has `$stateChangeSuccess`, which is fired once the page/state transition is complete. Just simply add a `$rootScope.$on` to the page controllers where you want stuff to happen on page changes.

http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', 
    function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ 
        console.log('Page change happened');
})
```