# Detect Page/URL changes on single page website using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, single-page-application

I'm trying to build a chrome extension where I need to insert some content on the webpage based on the page user currently is viewing.
Now, I'm having problems with single-page apps like Instagram, Linkedin, Pinterest, etc.
Because, on those websites, I can't detect if a user has moved to another page.

If you can help me with this issue, that would be a great help.

**Please Note:**

Before you mark this question as a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29811256/detect-page-change-for-one-page-apps-js) Question. I would like you to know, that question is closed now, and the only answer it has is for angular websites only. But I'm talking about all technologies, like Vue, React, Next, etc across all the web.

Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64297536/detect-url-change-of-spa-single-page-app-inside-iframe) question was for iframes only. Which also doesn't have a proper answer for all techs.

Thanks in advance